# How can you query a join or generic table generated by Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, join, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement Dynamic Entity Attribute Values on some of my entities. I have some generic classes that result in some tables in the database, but not being mapped to any `DbSets` I cannot access them from `DbContext`. Is there any way?

```
public class Person : Entity
{
  // ... some fields for personal data

        #region EntityAttributeValues
        public List<EntityAttributeValue<Person, EntityCategory<Person>>> EntityAttributeValues { get; set; }
        public List<EntityCategory<Person>> EntityCategories { get; set; }
        #endregion
}
```

And I add only `DbSet<Person>` to the `DbContext`.
After the migration, we have 2 more tables: `EntityCategory<Person>` table and the join table `EntityCategory<Person>Person`.
[See db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfxOe.png)

Now the problem is that I need somehow to write data to the `EntityCategory<Person>` table (i.e. CRUD the categories). Can this be done with EF or should I just go back to the future and use raw SQL?

UPDATE:
As per your request:

```
    public class EntityCategory<TEntity> :
        DiamondNode<EntityCategory<TEntity>>
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Attribute definitions for this type of entity and category
        /// </summary>
        public List<AttributeDefinition<EntityCategory<TEntity>>> AttributeDefinitions { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Entities assigned to this category
        /// </summary>
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<TEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
    public class EntityAttributeValue<TEntity, TEntityCategory> : BaseEntity
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
        where TEntityCategory : EntityCategory<TEntity>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The Attribute Definition Id.
        /// </summary>
        public Guid AttributeDefinitionId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attribute definition represents the metadata defining the attribute.
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey(nameof(AttributeDefinitionId))]
        public AttributeDefinition<TEntityCategory> AttributeDefinition { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The attribute value is held as JSON because of its type volatility.
        /// See DataType and AttributeDefinition for more information.
        /// </summary>
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public AttributeValue<TEntity> AttributeValue { get; set; }
    }
```

where

```
    public abstract class DiamondNode<TDiamondNode> : EnumerableEntity, IDiamondNode<TDiamondNode>
        where TDiamondNode : DiamondNode<TDiamondNode>
    {
        public List<TDiamondNode> Parents { get; set; }

        public List<TDiamondNode> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
    public class EnumerableEntity : NamedEntity, IHasReadonlyFlag
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// In case of seeding system defined data, this will be read only for seeds.
        /// </summary>
        public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Display order index
        /// </summary>
        public long OrderIndex { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Formatting and validity metadata
        /// </summary>
        public JsonDocument Metadata { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
    public /* abstract */ class BaseEntity
    {
       // public virtual Guid TenantId { get; set; }

        ///// <summary>
        ///// The unique identity Id of the entity.
        ///// </summary>
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Soft delete flag. The data access layer must implement the soft delete functionality.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Field for update/delete concurency detection mechanism.
        /// </summary>
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please share `EntityCategory` and `EntityAttributeValue`

Comment: Hi, please see the update. For the moment I added a DbSet to the DbContext for each generic entity and it seems it works, but I don't like this kind of redundant work because is prone to errors. Thanks.